# Bezier-Spline with Python adds unwanted point

Tags: python, bezier-curves

I have a list of points, and want to add a Bezier-spline using these points.

Following is my code:

```
import bpy

name = "MyCurve"
numPoints = 4
points = [ [1,1,1], [-1,1,1], [-1,-1,1], [1,-1,-1] ]

curvedata = bpy.data.curves.new(name=name,type='CURVE')
curvedata.dimensions = '3D'
curvedata.fill_mode = 'FULL'
curvedata.bevel_depth = 0.045     

ob = bpy.data.objects.new(name+"Obj", curvedata)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(ob)

polyline = curvedata.splines.new('BEZIER')
polyline.bezier_points.add(numPoints)
for num in range(numPoints):
    polyline.bezier_points[num].co = points[num]
polyline.resolution_u = 1

print( len(polyline.bezier_points))
```

Now my problem is, that this code adds another point. The printed value will be `5` not as I expected `4`. The added point is after the other points and is the point `(0, 0, 0)`. This is unwanted behavior.

What is wrong with my code?

My Blender version is 2.70 built 2014-03-19.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A new splines starts with a single point, it is not empty:

```
import bpy

curvedata = bpy.data.curves.new(name="Curve", type='CURVE')
ob = bpy.data.objects.new("CurveObj", curvedata)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(ob)

spline = curvedata.splines.new('BEZIER')
print(len(spline.bezier_points))
# Output: 1
```

The bezier spline has already a point, so you need to
`.add()` number of points you want to add minus 1.

```
polyline.bezier_points.add(len(points)-1)
```

By the way - you can assign the coordinates more efficiently like this:

```
from bpy_extras.io_utils import unpack_list
# ...
polyline.bezier_points.foreach_set("co", unpack_list(points))
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly. Do you have a quick reference/tutorial for the suggested assignment method for me?

Comment: `foreach_set()`: http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70a_release/bpy.types.bpy_prop_collection.html?highlight=foreach_set#bpy.types.bpy_prop_collection.foreach_set and for `unpack_list()` see the actual python script in `Blender/2.xx/scripts/modules/bpy_extras/io_utils.py`.