# The material shows black artifacts when rendered

Tags: python, materials, blender-internal-render-engine

This is what it looks in Blender[image]

This is what it looks after rendered

[image]

The atoms still looked fine but the bonds looked grainy even though (I think) I assigned the material to bonds the same way I did to atoms. This is the relevant part of my code

```
def colorize(data):
    for key in data.keys():

        D.materials.new(name=key)
        D.materials[key].diffuse_color = data[key]['color']
        D.materials[key].specular_intensity = 0.2

def draw(atoms, data):
    for atom in atoms:
        O.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(size=data[atom['name']]['radii']*0.5, location=atom['location'])
        O.object.shade_smooth()
        C.active_object.data.materials.append(D.materials[atom['name']])

def bonds():
    for c1 in D.objects:
        for c2 in D.objects:
            distance = pow(sum([(c2-c1)**2 for c1, c2 in zip(c1.location, c2.location)]), 0.5)
            if c1.name.startswith('Sphere') and c2.name.startswith('Sphere') and distance < 3:

                m = D.meshes.new('connector')

                bm = bmesh.new()
                v1 = bm.verts.new( c1.location )
                v2 = bm.verts.new( c2.location )
                e  = bm.edges.new([v1,v2])
                C.active_object.data.materials.append(D.materials['Stick'])

                bm.to_mesh(m)

                bond = D.objects.new( 'connector', m )
                C.scene.objects.link(bond)

                # Hook connector vertices to respective obj
                for i, obj in enumerate([ c1, c2 ]):
                    O.object.select_all( action = 'DESELECT' )
                    obj.select = True
                    bond.select = True
                    C.scene.objects.active = bond # Set connector as active

                    # Select vertex
                    O.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
                    bond.data.vertices[i].select = True
                    O.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

                    O.object.hook_add_selob() # Hook to obj

                    O.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
                    bond.data.vertices[i].select = False

                m = bond.modifiers.new('Skin', 'SKIN')
                m.use_smooth_shade = True
                m = bond.modifiers.new('Subsurf', 'SUBSURF' )
                m.levels = 2
                m.render_levels = 2
                C.active_object.data.materials.append(D.materials['Stick'])

                O.object.select_all( action = 'DESELECT' )

    for each in D.objects:
        if each.name.startswith('connector'):
            for v in each.data.skin_vertices[0].data:
                v.radius = 0.1, 0.1
            # print(D.materials['Stick'])
            print(C.object.active_material.diffuse_color)
            C.object.active_material.diffuse_color = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
            # C.object.active_material.diffuse_color = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

[image]

Comment: It looks to me like you have overlapping (or duplicated) faces creating Z-fighting

Comment: Hey, nice use of Python there! It would be helpful if you could post the .blend using [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). Have you tried isolating the part of your script that handles materials and testing just that?

Comment: @cegaton I can't tell which part of the code in the bond() function actually caused the overlapping faces

Comment: @Mentalist Oh. Thanks for letting me know about Blend Exchange. I added to my post.

Comment: After taking a quick look at your .blend I can confirm that z-fighting is the culprit. Some part of your script is causing the same geometry to be created redundantly. Since this duplicate geometry occupies the same space, the render engine cannot tell which planar surface should receive precedence and hence the z-fighting. On each of the objects that form the bonds you have a modifier chain (Hook, Hook, Skin, Subsurf) that is sufficient for creating the bonds. Once you figure out how to create the geometry as a single instance you should be good.

Comment: Also, I'm no Python wizard, but... if it were me I would *aim* to create a script that builds all the bonds as a *single* mesh object. I mean it would calculate all the vertices that would be at the centers of the spheres (atoms), then calculate which verts need to form edges and make those, then add the necessary modifiers on the object to result in a renderable mesh.

Comment: @Mentalist Thank you so much for the suggestion. Not sure if I fully understand, but I don't think I can solely create bonds without creating atoms because I need the bonds to connect these atoms (since when they're moving, and I want the bonds to remain connecting to the atoms).

Comment: I found it. The overlapping faces resulted from "for c1 in D.objects: for c2 in D.objects:" So there's a double counting issue here. I fixed this by using "itertools.combinations" instead.

Comment: @MickKrongchon For whatever reason I didn't notice your follow-up comment at the time you posted it, but thanks for sharing the solution for others to learn from. Glad you got it sorted. :-)