# Delete a single vertex from a spline

Tags: python, bezier-curves

I want to create a curve with 4 points in python. So i figured that I could subdivide a primitive curve twice and delete one of the points. The code below kinda works by selecting a single point and deleting it. Well, except that by default *all* points are selected so this simply deletes all the points. I suppose that I can loops through all the points and handles and deselect that way. But you can deselect everything by a single mouseclick (or a single command in object mode), so isn't there a easier/more elegant way to do this?

```
bpy.ops.curve.primitive_bezier_curve_add(enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD')
my_curve= bpy.context.active_object                

bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.ops.curve.subdivide()
bpy.ops.curve.subdivide()
my_curve.data.splines[0].bezier_points[3].select_control_point = True
bpy.ops.curve.delete(type='VERT')

bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
```

[image: This is what I get prior to the delete command]

Comment: Actually the looping works fine and isn't so cumbersome. But I'm still interested in a better understanding of manipulating curves, so any answer to my question would still be valued.

Comment: [What really is the question here?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). To create a spline from points would not go anywhere using code above  Dupe of intention:    https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120074/how-to-make-a-curve-path-from-scratch-given-a-list-of-x-y-z-points  .  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/180148/create-curve-from-numpy-array-using-python

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110177/connecting-two-points-with-a-line-curve-via-python-script  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127603/how-to-specify-nurbs-path-vertices-in-python

Comment: Thanks for insightfull feedback. I didn't state clearly that I had to use subdivide when I create the curve and then remove unwanted points

Comment: It's becoming clearer. To clarify further is it also a requirement to subdivide twice instead of once with `number_cuts = 2`. ?

Comment: number of cuts?! I didn't know that one. I think that is a lot more what I need. Thanks!